# Conda insatllation is removed after BASH location changed

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I changed my BASH PATH on Linux, but I don't get the miniconda which was installed in my system. It seems it is removed, please help to reverse the change.

I added the following line to `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

and then the following command to apply the changes:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

For `echo $PATH` , the output is -

```
/home/abhisek062/bin:/home/abhisek062/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! What method did you use to change your PATH. Please post the exact command and be specific. Also, please post the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: ```nano ~/.bashrc ```
```export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"```
```source ~/.bashrc```
```echo $PATH```

The output is - 
```/home/abhisek062/bin:/home/abhisek062/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin```

Answer (score 1):

Please don't messed up your `~/bashrc`. to revert the default bashrc run :

`cp -fv /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc`

The Conda Prefix Default is already in `PREFIX=$HOME/miniconda3`. if you need change your prefix re-run `Miniconda3.sh` script or
Change it in **Conda Init Section** on `~/.bashrc`:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/shibuya/Data/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "$HOME/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "$HOME/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

**The PATH** should be :

`$HOME/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the line you added to `~/.bashrc` as this is not needed. Delete the `export $HOME/bin` line from `~/.bashrc`

To explain:

The `$HOME/bin` directory is automatically added to your PATH when you log in, if and only if the directory exists. Therefore, when you first create the `$HOME/bin` directory, you will need to log out and log back in to update your PATH. Subsequently when you log in, `$HOME/bin` will automatically add to your PATH.

If you look at your `~/.profile` file, you will see the code responsible for automatically adding the PATH:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Additionally, you may notice that your current PATH shows `/home/abhisek062/bin` is listed twice. This is because the `export $HOME/bin` line in `~/.bashrc` is not needed.

---

In conclusion, delete the `export` line you added to `~/.bashrc` and then run the following command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will reverse the change. Please comment below if this doesn't restore access to miniconda.

Comment: If this doesn't restore access to miniconda, what is the path to miniconda? Maybe this needs to be added to your current PATH.

Comment: Look at this code- 

```abhisek062@abhisek-PC:~/Downloads$ export ~/.bashrc```

```bash: export: `/home/abhisek062/.bashrc': not a valid identifier```

This is not working

Comment: How can I check the PATH of miniconda?

Comment: @Abhisek You can try `which miniconda` or `whereis miniconda` to find out where it is. However, other [users on reddit report problems adding miniconda to your PATH manually](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/7dsjl6/comment/dq06all/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and it may be best to call the command using the full path to avoid mixing up your system python with the miniconda python.

Comment: @Abhisek Also, sorry for the typo. It should be `source ~/.bashrc`, not `export ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Okay, but it is also not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138017/discussion-between-abhisek-and-mchid).

Comment: I directly run source ~/.bashrc but it not worked 


```abhisek062@abhisek-PC:~/Desktop$ which miniconda```
```abhisek062@abhisek-PC:~/Desktop$ whereis miniconda```
miniconda:
```abhisek062@abhisek-PC:~/Desktop$```

For your kind information last time I want to say I edited the bashrc file and removed all content and then i added following content - $ export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"